# Does Laravel Orion works with Laravel version 6

Tags: php, laravel, rest, eloquent, laravel-6

Using Laravel Orion with laravel version 6

Defined orion api resource in api.php

```
Orion::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Facing error

[image]

It might be a change of syntax from laravel 6 to 8

Answer (score 0):

Got the right syntax for laravel 6

```
Orion::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Thanks